# Чем открыть файл с расширением pxm на windows?

Tags: design

Люди помогите умоляю, есть умный дизайнер который работает на Mac OS, он сделал макет сайта с расширением .pxm, а я (бедный верстальщик) не могу найти подходящую программу (альтернативу pixelmator MacOS) чтобы открыть этот файл на Windows.
Подскажите пожалуйста какую программу надо.Впервые с таким расширением работаю.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю подходит это вам или нет, но есть онлайн сервис позволяющий сконвертировать xpm в PNG
https://www.coolutils.com/ru/online/PXM-to-PNG